# Why do we need a pointer here

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm new to C++, and while going through pointers I don't quite understand why I need to use `*p` in the `while` loop condition check below.

It is a very simple function that counts occurrences of the character `x` in the array, with an example invocation as in the below `main()` function. We assume here that `p` will point to an array of chars. Purely for demonstration.

```
int count(char* p, char x) {
    int count = 0;
    while (*p != NULL) { // why *p requried here if p is already a pointer? 
        if (x == *p) count++;
        p++;
    }
    return count;
}

int main(){
    char a[5] = {'a','a','c','a',NULL};
    char* p = a; 
    std::cout << count(p, 'a') << std::endl; 
}
```

Why do I need

```
while (*p != NULL)
```

Since `p` is already a pointer, I thought

```
while (p != NULL)
```

should be enough, but the program crashes.

Comment: Both `NULL`s should have been `0` (or `'\0'`) instead because they are `char` values and not pointers.

Comment: That's abusing `NULL` for things that are not pointers, such as `*p` and `a[4]`
. If you use the less ancient `nullptr` instead you will get a compilation error.

Comment: There is a `NULL` is main. That's what the loop is looking for.

Comment: At the top of your code `#undef NULL` then `#define NULL nullptr`, then you'll notice all the misuse of `NULL`.

Comment: @Eljay tbh, any use of NULL in C++ is a misuse... the need to include a C header to get it is a hint (and in some implementations it is defined as 0). Before `nullptr_t` was introduced , the proper way was not compare equality at all - either by implicit or explicit cast to `bool`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Incrementing the pointer will make it point to the next element in the character array. Incrementing the pointer will never make it equal to a nullpointer or  `NULL`.

c-strings are nul-terminated. The end of the string is marked with an element with value `'\0'`. In main this is the last element of the array and the loop in the function will stop when it reaches that last element.

`p` is the pointer to the element. `*p` is the element.

Using `NULL` for that condition is misleading. `NULL` should not be used in C++ anymore. A null pointer is `nullptr` and the terminator in strings is `'\0'`. The code works nevertheless because `NULL` just happens to equal `0`  and `'\0'`. Tough, it was meant to be used for pointers, not for `char`.

The code can be written like this:

```
int count(char* p, char x) {

    int count = 0;
    while (*p != '\0') { // why *p requried here if p is already a pointer? 
        if (x == *p) count++;
        p++;
    }
    return count;

}

int main(){

    char a[5] = {'a','a','c','a','\0'};
    std::cout << count(a, 'a') << std::endl; 
}
```

Or better, use `std::string` and `std::count`:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorith>

int main() { 
     std::string s{"aaca"};
     std::cout << std::count(s.begin(),s.end(),'a'); 
}
```

Note that string literals automatically include the terminator. So `"aaca"` is a `const char[5]`, an array of 5 characters, and the last one is `'\0'`. With `std::string` the details are a little hairy, but `s[4]` is also `'\0'`. Note that this is in contrast to other containers, where `container[container.size()]` is out-of-bounds and wrong.

Comment: `NULL is defined via a macro and its value equals 0 and '\0'.` note that this is not guaranteed by the c++ standard. `NULL` may expand to any null pointer literal. That includes `nullptr`, in which case the example program is not so much misleading but rather simply illformed.

Comment: @eerorika right, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

`p` is a pointer to `char`. So if you check the value of `p` it will be an address to that `char` (the first `char` in a string or array). So that address will be non-zero whether you are pointing to the first character or the last character.

In C or C++ strings are traditionally null terminated, meaning that the end of a string is marked by the null-terminator which is a single char with the value 0. To check the value of the `char` that the pointer `p` is pointing to, you need to de-reference it. De-referencing is done by prepending a `*` to the expression. In this case we extract the value that `p` is pointing to and not the address that `p` points to.

You are basically having an array of `char`, and as an example it might look like this in memory:

| Address | ASCII value | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 97 (0x61) | a |
| 1001 | 97 (0x61) | a |
| 1002 | 99 (0x63) | c |
| 1003 | 97 (0x61) | a |
| 1004 | 0 (0x00) | NULL |

To begin with will point to the first char, that is address 1000, so the value of `p` is 1000, and the value of `*p` is 97 or 'a'. As you increment `p` it will change to 1001, 1002, etc. until it gets to 1004 where the value of `p` is 1004 and the value of `*p` will be 0.

Had you written `while (p != NULL)` instead of `*p` you would essentially have checked whether `1004 != 0` which would be true, and you would continue past the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I know a lot of (older) tutorials start with (naked) pointers and "C" style arrays but they are really not the first things you should use.
If possible in C++ try to write solutions not depending in pointers.
For holding text, use std::string.

```
#include <string>       // stop using char* for text
#include <algorithm>    // has the count_if method
#include <iostream>     

int count_matching_characters(const std::string& string, char character_to_match)
{
    int count{ 0 };

    // range based for loop, looping over al characters in the string
    for (const char c : string)
    {
        if (c == character_to_match) count++;
    }
    return count;

    // or using a lambda function and algorithm
    /*
    return std::count_if(string.begin(), string.end(), [&](const char c)
    {
        return (character_to_match == c);
    });
    **/
}

int main()
{
    int count = count_matching_characters("hello world", 'l');
    std::cout << count;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be better to use `std::string_view` instead of `std::string` .

Comment: @eerorika for constant strings yes I agree. But string_views come with their own lifecycle considerations. (I didn't want to go down that rabbit hole yet ;) ).

Comment: `count_if` was also my first idea, but there is also `count`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes i forgot about that too. And then decided the  syntax for lambdas might still be a bit too weird.